# how to format short format date to short format in aspx code?

Tags: asp.net, .net

In my aspx page I have repeater binding with date. It is showing full date and I want to format it to short date. Please guide me how to format date in aspx code (not in C# or Vb)

Here is my code:

```
<a class="CalendarLinks" href="readmore.aspx?wkdate=<%# Eval("cldID") %>">
                                <%# Eval("cldDate")%></a>
```

Thanks

Comment: The underlying language used in aspx is C# or VB.NET. All you have to do is convert the date to short format before you display it /store it. We can help you better if you can edit your question and add some code that you currently have and the exact location where you want the conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use overloaded Eval to pass the format

```
<a class="CalendarLinks" href="readmore.aspx?wkdate=<%# Eval("cldID") %>">
                                <%# Eval("cldDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%></a>
```

Comment: Is Eval part of aspx? Or is it a member of DataBinder class?

Comment: At run time, the Eval method calls the Eval method of the DataBinder object, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @GaneshR. in both ways will there be any difference ? for use of format function ?

Comment: @user576510 I just wanted to know which .NET class was providing the functionality. Just like HashSet has Contains method and so does Linq (Contains is provided as an Extension method). But I know using HashSets Contains is better.